# Nativescript Page Transition Crash: "Application tried to present modally an active controller"

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, nativescript, transition

My app crashes sometimes when I go through a certain page transition on iOS. The error I get is:

```
*** JavaScript call stack:
(
0   UIApplicationMain@[native code]
1   start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:272:26
2   anonymous@file:///app/app.js:128:26
3   evaluate@[native code]
4   moduleEvaluation@:1:11
5   @:7:48
6   promiseReactionJob@:1:11
)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <UINavigationControllerImpl: 0x1120d5a00>.'
```

My current app has:

- A main TabView page with three tabs
- page A
- page B

On the 3rd tab of the main view, there is a button that takes you to page A.
On page A, there is a button that takes you to page B.
Finally, page B has a button that sets the the tabIndex of the main view to 1, followed by navigating to the main view (with the expected result of seeing tab 1 at this point).

It is when I try to navigate from page B to the main view that I get the error (but not all the time). I tried commenting out `tabView.setTabIndex(1);` and `animated: true,clearHistory: true`, but that didn't help.

```
        var tabView = require("~/views/main-tab/main-tab.js");

        tabView.setTabIndex(1); // the second tab out of three
        truthView.reset();
        lieView.reset();

        utilsModule.GC();

        const navigationEntry = {

            moduleName: "views/main-tab/main-tab",
            animated: true,
            clearHistory: true

        };
        var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
        topmost.navigate(navigationEntry);
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Best wishes,
Nat

Comment: can you please add your routing code as well? May be nested routing and clearHistory creating problem here

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Hey :) What do you mean by the routing code? I am using Javascript and XML. Routing is just for Angular?

Comment: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/smooth-page-transitions-on-android/114/6 May be something realted to this